# Confused creating a DynamoDB query

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having the below data in dynamo DB

```
id  category    value   rule
1     a            5    1
2     b            5    1
3     c            5    1
4     a            5    2
5     b            5    2
6     a            2    3
7     b            2    3
8     a            3    4
9     b            3    4
10    c            2    4
11    d            2    4
12    b            5    5
13    c            5    5
```

Here my target is as below.

1. First scan the table and get the `rule` with size `2`. once I get that rule, check if it has only `a` and `b` in category. Ignore the rest.

Here is my current query.

```
var array=["a","b"];
 for (index = 1; index <= 5; ++index) {
        console.log(index);
        var params1 = {
            TableName: "MyCatTable",
            FilterExpression: "#rule=:rule",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#rule": "rule"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":rule": String(index)
            }
        };

        results.push(dynamodb.scan(params1).promise().then(function (data) {
            if (data.Items.length == 2 && (array.indexOf(data.Items[0].category) >= 0)) {
                var uw = data.Items;
                return uw;
            }
        }));
    }
    return Promise.all(results);
}).then((data) => {
    var res;
    console.log("----------------------");
    console.log(data);
})
```

when I run this it is returning me the rules `2`, `3` and `5`. But I need only `2` and `3`. since `5` has `b` and `c` instead of `a` and `b`.

or is there any other way of filtering out the json response that I get?

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this part of the code:

```
data.Items[0].category
```

it only checks the category of the first element on the "data.Items" array, you need to filter the array by checking the category of each element instead of just the first one. The reason that 5 is returned is because the first element of 5 is 'b' which exists in your array.

*edited - code fragment as requested (this should be a rough outline of how the code should look. there might be a few errors though)

```
if (data.Items.length == 2) {
            var uw = [];
            for(var x in data.Items){
                if(array.indexOf(x.category) >= 0) uw.push(x);
            }
            return uw;
        }
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. I'm confused on how can I do it :(. Can you please help  me with a small code fragment? Thanks

Comment: @user3872094 added the fragment as requested

Comment: This is really helpful ...:)