# create a json without undefined

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-dynamodb

I'm writing a code where in I need to do a dynamodb scan and there I need to create a array response with the values, when I do it, it is adding `undefined`.
this is an extension to my previous queestion [Confused creating a DynamoDB query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275109/confused-creating-a-dynamodb-query/48275277#48275277)

Here is my code.

```
var results = [];
var array=["a","b"];
for (index = 1; index <= 5; ++index) {
        var params1 = {
        TableName: "MyCatTable",
        FilterExpression: "#rule=:rule",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#rule": "rule"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":rule": String(index)
        }
};
results.push(dynamodb.scan(params1).promise().then(function (data) {
                if (data.Items.length == 2) {
                    var uw = [];
                    console.log("Entered");
                    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        if (array.indexOf(data.Items[i].category) >= 0) {
                            console.log("pushing");
                            uw.push(data.Items[i].category);
                        }
                    }
                    if (uw.length > 1) {
                        return uw;
                    } else return "x";

                } else {
                    return "x";
                }
            }));
        }
    return Promise.all(results);
}).then((data) => {
    console.log("----------------------");
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

when I run this code I get the output as

```
[
  'x',
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['a', 'b'],
  'x',
  'x'
]
```

here when I remove `return "x"`, the output that I get is

```
[
  undefined,
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['a', 'b'],
  undefined,
  undefined
]
```

I want to know if there is a way to get

```
[
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['a', 'b'],
]
```

Comment: I don't know if you can avoid to return when the result is undefined. But what you could do is to filter your results as `data.filter(d => d)` removing the `undefined` values.

Comment: @Striped ... and also falsy values. Suggest `data.filter(d => d !== undefined)`.

Comment: Thanks @user202729 and Striped... This worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the comment to an answer.

---

The problem of removing `undefined` values from Javascript array has been solved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/281264), the simplest way is to use `filter` function (ES6).

```
data.filter(d => d !== undefined)
```

will return the array with `undefined` values removed.

Also, note that the reason why the `undefined` values are in the array in the first place is, [return nothing returns `undefined` in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3717548).